# non-degenerate 2 forms, dimension and wedge product

Tags: linear-algebra, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, tensors, exterior-algebra

Consider the problem from my assignment on tensor forms:

Problem: We say that a 2-form n on a vector space V is non-degenerate of for $u\in V$ , n(u,v)=0 for all v$\in V$ implies u=0. Let w be a non-degenerate 2-form on a vector space V.

Then show that:(a) Show that V is even dimensional.

(b) If dim(V)= 2n, show that there exists a basis {$e^{*}_1,...,e^{*}_{2n}$} of $V^{*}$ such $w=e^{*}_{1} \bigwedge e^{*}_{n+1} + e^{*}_2 \bigwedge e^{*}_{n+2} + e^{*}_n \bigwedge e^{*}_{2n}$.

Thoughts:(a)Let on the contrary V is odd dimensional. But I am not sure what result should I use to proceed towards contradiction.

(b) I have to construct such a basis. $V^{*}$ will also have a dimension 2n.  I have studied wedge product and it's properties from my class notes but I am  still not sure how can I proceed towards  such a construction.

Kindly give some hints.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To show the space is even dimensional,
let $v_1,\dots, v_n$ be a basis, define $ \omega_{ij} = \omega(v_i,v_j)$ so you can think this a matrix coefficient. Show this matrix is skew-symmetric (i.e $A^T = -A $) . Show that this matrix invertible using non-degeneracy.
Then proof is reduced to showing every skew-symmetric matrix of odd dimension is singular. Use $\det(A) = \det(A^T)$ and being skew-symmetric.

Constructing such basis of dual space is same as finding a basis such that
$$\omega(e_i,e_{i+n}) = 1 $$
and
$$\omega(e_i,e_j) = 0 \text{  when }|j-i|\neq n$$
Pick a basis than apply gram-schmidt but instead of inner product use the 2 form

Comment: You assumed a basis of V but it is nowhere written that V is finite dimensional.